# How do I redirect my URL to the app store app page?

Tags: redirect, safari, app-store

I noticed that when I type Path.com in mobile safari on my iphone, it redirects me to the app store. And when I'm using my desktop browser (safari, as well), it just goes to the path.com website. I'd like to do this for my site. What do I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
window.location.href="myURL.com"</script>
```